# Efficient filtering on Spark SQL dataframes with ordered keys

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I've got a Spark SQL dataframe containing a "key" column. The queries I want to run start by filtering on the key range. My question in outline: **is it possible to sort the dataframe by key so as to do efficient key range filters, before subsequently running a more complex SQL query?**

I'm aware that such efficient filtering is possible for key-value RDDs, i.e. RDDs over Tuple2, using PairRDDFunctions. My workflow currently looks as follows:

```
// Create a dataframe
val df: DataFrame = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM ...")
val keyValRDD = df.rdd.map( (r: Row) => (r.getAs[String]("key"), r) )

// Sort by key - and cache.
val keyValRDDSorted = keyValRDD.sortByKey().cache

// Define a function to run SQL query on a range. 
def queryRange(lower: String, upper: String, sql: String, tableName: String) = {
    val rangeRDD = keyValRDDSorted.filterByRange(lower, upper)
    val rangeDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rangeRDD.map{ _._2 }, df.schema)
    rangeDF.createTempView(tableName)
    sqlContext.sql(sql)
}

// Invoke multiple times.
queryRange(...)
queryRange(...)
...
```

This works, and is efficient in that only the partitions containing the relevant key range are processed. However, I understand that Spark SQL uses an optimised storage format as compared to a plain RDD. The above workflow can't take advantage of this, as it is the key-value RDD that is cached.

So, my specific question: **Is there a more efficient way of achieving the desired result?**

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: I fell that you are confounding RDDs with DqtaFrames

Comment: Hi Alberto, thanks for your comment, and sorry if there is confusion. I'm using dataframes because I want to run SQL queries. I'm using RDDs because this is the only way I know of to sort on a selected key (column) and do efficient range queries on that key. My question boils down to whether I really need to resort to RDDs in order to do this.

Comment: I don't understand why you have to sort the records.

Comment: I want to sort the records because I'm doing range filters on the keys. By sorting the records in advance, I avoid a full table scan for the range filters. Note that I'm sorting once, then caching, then doing multiple (efficient) range queries on the cached data.

Comment: So you want to use some kind of [window](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Alberto, but I don't think windows functions will help here: I'm interested in retrieving filtered row ranges, not on computing values over these. I've re-phrased my question slightly to make it clear that I'm doing repeated queries over the cached data, and that the queries are filters.